# Does limitToLast(int) download the entire data under the database reference?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose, I have a DatabaseReference which refers to a database where keys and values are stored. Suppose I want to get the top 10 values. So, if I use `orderByValue().limitToLast(10)`, *will it download the entire data under the reference or only the top 10 values?* I am asking this question because, as you know, after a certain limit, every downloaded GB is charged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not **top 10**, but it will download from ordered bottom 10 items only. Yes it will not take extra data.

You can read references on

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#limit-queries

and

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#limitToLast(int)

Enable offline capabilities of real time database in order to save extra GBs